# Expand variadic arguments to another method without cost

Tags: c#, string, variadic

In C# how do you pass a list of variadic arguments to another method that accepts a variadic list, preferably without much cost?

E.g.:

```
class StringHelper
{
    public string Concat(params string[] values)
    {
        lock (_stringBuilder)
        {
            Clear();
            for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                _stringBuilder.Append(values[i]);
            return _stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}

static class StringUtilShared
{
    static readonly StringHelper _stringHelper = new StringHelper(256);

    public static string Concat(this string str, params string[] values)
    {
        return _stringHelper.Concat(str, /* pass args here! */);
    }
}
```

Comment: your question seems unclear

Comment: @Ehsan I believe OP needs to prefix `values` with the additional value `str` in order to pass it as one list to `Concat`.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica Would that automatically unwrap the array to individual strings? In any case, this gives me an error because the method doesn't accept a `string` and `string[]`.

Comment: @Badminton I realised that your `Concat` method only took `string[] values` immediately after I wrote that comment. Sorry!

Comment: If by "without too much cost", you mean "without creating a new array", then I don't think this is possible. You will have to create a new array and copy the contents.

Comment: @Sweeper yes without creating a new array other other expensive workarounds. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: Are you able to edit `StringHelper` by any chance?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, can edit anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using methods that accept arrays, your methods should accept `IEnumerable<string>`s. Since they are just "iterators", there's no need to copy all the elements when you want an extra element to be passed.

First, put the actual logic of `Concat` in a method that accepts `IEnumerable<string>`, and have a variadic overload of `Concat` that calls the `IEnumerable<string>` overload:

```
class StringHelper
{
    public string Concat(IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        lock (_stringBuilder)
        {
            Clear();
            foreach (string value in values)
                _stringBuilder.Append(value);
            return _stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string Concat(params string[] values) {
        return Concat((IEnumerable<string>)values);
    }
}
```

Now, you can call the `IEnumerable<string>` overload in the extension method:

```
public static string Concat(this string str, params string[] values)
{
    return _stringHelper.Concat(values.Prepend(str));
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! (btw, I think you meant `foreach`?)

Comment: @BadmintonCat Ah yes! The problem with knowing too many languages...